# Android audio effect limits to 5 bands

Tags: android, audio, equalizer

I use Android [Audio Effect/Equalizer API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Equalizer.html) for my app. However, it limits to 5 bands. Is there any document/library that helps to tune more bands for a finer equalizer implementation?

Comment: Can't you just use more than one instance of the equalizer to get more bands?

Comment: I use one instance of the equalizer that is attached to [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#getAudioSessionId()](MediaPlayer's AudioSessionId)

Comment: @NilsPipenbrinck: Use of more then one instance of the equalizer will convert in to same another 5 band frequency. Then how it is possible to have all frequency different? Do have any other idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It varies from device to device `getNumberOfBands` tell you the number of **Equalizer effect**. Some devices have 5,8 and 13,etc.

```
Equalizer equalizer = new Equalizer(0,mediaplayer.getAudioSessionId());

equalizer.setEnabled(true);

equalizer.getNumberOfBands(); //it tells you the number of equalizer in device.
```

Also have a look at [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30477747/3496570)

Comment: I tried this on three different devices (Samsung, Huawei, Nexus). All give 5 bands. Whereas PowerAmp (Music Player) available on playstore gives 10 bands for every device. Any idea how they are doing this?

Comment: I have tested it on different devices and returns sometimes 15 and sometime 5. And I don't know how PowerAmp does this for 10 bands

Answer (score 4):

This question was asked long ago. Here is a solution for people seeking answer in future. I have found this library for android that provides 10band Equalizer.

Using Android's Equalizer Api on three different devices I was able to get the following result:

1) Samsung Galaxy Note 3 (5 Bands)

2) Huawei Mate 8 (5 Bands)

3) Nexus 5 (5 bands)

using [this](https://github.com/h6ah4i/android-openslmediaplayer) library I am able to get 10bands on all of the above devices. I have tested it and it is working great.

Include [this](https://github.com/h6ah4i/android-openslmediaplayer) library in your project. And use the following code to have an Equalizer with 10 bands.

```
IMediaPlayerFactory mediaPlayerFactory = new OpenSLMediaPlayerFactory(getApplicationContext());
IBasicMediaPlayer mediaPlayer = mediaPlayerFactory.createMediaPlayer();
IEqualizer equalizer = mediaPlayerFactory.createHQEqualizer();
/* This returns 10 bands exactly like Poweramp music app does */
int numOfBands = equalizer.getNumberOfBands();
```

This library has is documentation that you can refer as-well. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The number of bands and their center frequencies are dependent upon the handset. The equalizer implementation is baked into the ROM.

Answer (score 0):

You can try having a try with [sasken-player](https://code.google.com/p/sasken-player/source/browse/), it's a reimplementation of the equalizer that will give you 10 bands