# How can I create 10 frequency sound bands seekbar equalizer in android

Tags: android, audio, frequency, equalizer

Can somebody help me in creating a 10 frequency bands equalizer for android as I don't have any idea how i can create it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android audio effect limits to 5 bands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12545571/android-audio-effect-limits-to-5-bands)

Comment: Thank you for you response. Not exactly, because I wanted to know if there is any way through which i can create 10 bands always for each device on which I play music. Do know any such way?